# Set Bit at Index i in Z3

Tags: z3

I am trying to set set a bit at a particular index in a bit vector in z3.

Currently, I use bit-wise or to accomplish this. I am working with large bit vectors (over a 1000 bits) and believe this is a causing the solver to take a significant amount of time. I was hoping their was a way that was faster than this to set an arbitrary bit in a bit-vector (similar to the store used by Arrays).

Is there a better way to do this, or am I stuck just using the bit-wise or?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if it would be faster, but you can always do an assert like this:

```
(assert (= ((_ extract i i) bv) #b1))
```

to tell the solver that the `i`th bit of `bv` is high. Whether this is usable in your particular application depends on how those new expressions are passed around, of course. If this trick doesn't work for you, I think you are stuck with the bitwise-or.

Answer (score 3):

In addition, for bit-vectors one can use a combination of extract and concatenation to form new bit-vectors from old ones. For example

```
   (concat ((_ extract n-1 k+1) x) y ((_ extract k-1 0) x))
```

where y is a bit-vector of length 1, should have the effect of forming a bit-vector that is equal to x except for the position k, where it is defined by y.